# Matching by market cap two large data frames

Tags: r, matlab, match

I have a tricky problem in managing the dataset for my thesis (which is about the implied volatility surface of REITs options). I am supposed to find the names of the companies (with options listed on them) ,that are not REITs, whose market caps is similar to the one of a list of REITs I already have. I have a very large dataset with daily obs (from 2005 to 2014) for the market caps of 71 REITs and the same dataset for all non-REITs names listed in US (already cleaned for extreme values of market cap). I've been told that I should perform a many-to-many match by year, get the differences in market caps (REITs - non REITs) and eliminate everything that's outside a +/- 10% tolerance band. I'm really a beginner both in R and Matlab and I have no idea on how I should do this match. Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), for instance with a subset of your data or fake data?

Comment: you need to make a cross join between Treit and Tnonreit (both tables of <id, mcap>). A cross join in matlab is done as such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053110/full-outer-join-of-two-tables/31068712#31068712

Comment: 'data.frame': 14005066 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ X             : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ secid         : int  5139 5139 5139 5139 5139 5139 5139 5139 5139 5139 ...
 $ date          : Date, format: "2010-05-19" "2010-06-10" ...
 ..............
 $ market.cap    : num  2370217 2311218 2212696 2962410 2772855 ... this is the structure of one of the two datasets. the other one is similar but with different names (and more variables also)

Answer (score -1):

(in matlab) You need to make a cross join between Treit and Tnonreit (both tables of ). A cross join in matlab is done as such: [Full outer join of two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053110/full-outer-join-of-two-tables/31068712#31068712)
then compare the mcap_left vs mcap-right and discard given your threshold, this will leave you with pairs of  which have similar mcaps